# SQL joins conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables t1, t2 and t3. Below are their schemas.

I need to join them and do have the condition.

- In t1 table, objectName can be one of 4: 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI',  or 'JKL'.
- If t1.objectName is 'ABC', I need to join t1.idObject with t2.id1.
- If t1.objectName is 'DEF', I need to join t1.idObject with with t2.id2.
- If t1.objectName is 'GHI', I need to join t1.idObject with t2.id3.
- If t1.objectName is 'JKL', I need to join t1.idObject with t3.id4.

I need to select t1.idObject, t1.objectName, t2.custName, t3.Message.

```
create table t1 (idObject int, objectName varchar(20));
create table t2 (id1 int, id2 int, id3 int, custName varchar(20));
create table t3 (id4 int, Message varchar(20));

insert into t1 values (101, 'ABC'), (102, 'DEF'), (103, 'GHI'), (104, 'JKL'), (105, 'ABC'), (106, 'DEF'), (107, 'GHI'), (108, 'JKL');

insert into t2 values (101, 102, 103, 'Val'), (105, 106, 107, 'Mil');

insert into t3 values (104, 'Message1'), (108, 'Messgage2');

select * from t1;
select * from t2;
select * from t3;
```

Query with explanation will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: hm a "normal" join won't do it here I think, in t-sql you would do this with an apply, but afaik mysql does not support applys. curious how that would work here...

Comment: in the JKL case, how do you join to the t2 table

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
    t1.idObject, 
    t1.objectName, 
    t2.custName, 
    t3.Message
FROM 
    t1
LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.idObject = (
        CASE
            WHEN t1.objectName = 'ABC' THEN t2.id1
            WHEN t1.objectName = 'DEF' THEN t2.id2
            WHEN t1.objectName = 'GHI' THEN t2.id3
        ELSE 0
        END 
    )
LEFT JOIN t3
    ON t1.idObject = (
        CASE
            WHEN t1.objectName = 'JKL' THEN t3.id4
        ELSE 0
        END 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a combination of left joins and coalesce().  This is the general idea.

```
select coalesce(t2.value, t3.value, t4.value) theValue
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on something
left join table2 t3 on something else
left join table2 t4 on something different
where whatever
```